# Comparar mes actual vs mes anterior mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Tengo un problema con un query, necesito que me obtenga el número de día (1,2,3 etc), un conteo del mes anterior y un conteo del mes actual.

He probado un par de cosas diferentes y lo más cerca que he estado de obtener algo es con este query:

```sql
SELECT
    DAY(DATE(ultimo_contacto)) AS dia,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(tipologia)
    FROM
        base_gestorbase_ATONE
    WHERE
        tipologia = 'Contacto'
        AND YEAR(ultimo_contacto) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND MONTH(ultimo_contacto) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    GROUP BY
        DAY(DATE(ultimo_contacto))) AS 'anterior',
    COUNT(tipologia) AS 'actual'
FROM
    contacto
WHERE
    MONTH(ultimo_contacto) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND tipologia = 'Contacto'
GROUP BY
    DAY(DATE(ultimo_contacto))
```

El problema es que me devuelve estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo que debería de devolver es un 0 en el día 13 del campo "anterior".

Alguien sabe qué podía estar mal o alguna otra manera de hacerlo? También probé con un CASE pero me devolvía todos los campos NULL en "anterior" y "actual".

Comment: no se entiende bien el requerimiento, por qué 0 cuando es 13? a qué te refieres con conteo del mes anterior y del actual?

Comment: Sí, me refiero al conteo. El día 13 debería de tener en "anterior" un 0 en lugar de un 1. En otras palabras, está haciendo mal el conteo.

Comment: pero conteo de qué? esa es mi pregunta

Comment: Hace un conteo del campo "tipología", básicamente busca si tipologia = 'Contacto'. Es lo que está en el where de la consulta

Comment: @RicardoPortillo Por favor, pásanos tu dataset en SQL con phpmyadmin->exportar con unos datos de muestra e indícanos qué resultado te gustaría obtener para ese ejemplo concreto

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que necesitas comparar el mes actual con el anterior agrupando por día y condicionando por la columna tipología donde debe ser igual a **"Contacto"**.

Realice esta consulta con datos inventados, ya que, no dejaste datos de muestra, más lo que se visibiliza en la imagen.

```
SELECT DAY(ultimo_contacto) AS dia,
(SELECT COUNT(ultimo_contacto) FROM tabla_prueba 
 WHERE DAY(ultimo_contacto) = dia
 AND MONTH(ultimo_contacto) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
 AND YEAR(ultimo_contacto) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
 AND tipologia = 'Contacto') AS anterior,
(SELECT count(ultimo_contacto) FROM tabla2_prueba 
 WHERE DAY(ultimo_contacto) = dia
 AND MONTH(ultimo_contacto) = MONTH(NOW())
 AND YEAR(ultimo_contacto) = YEAR(NOW())
 AND tipologia = 'Contacto') AS actual
FROM tabla_prueba WHERE MONTH(ultimo_contacto) = MONTH(NOW()) AND 
YEAR(ultimo_contacto) = YEAR(NOW()) AND tipologia = 'Contacto'
GROUP BY dia;
```

Quiero destacar que esto lo hice con una solo tabla y tú por lo que vi usas dos, pero en ese caso solo cambias uno de los select.